# More confusing behavior with stopPropagation()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following code It takes a `<ul>` and it drops down the contents when clicked. That works great. The problem was that it would also close other menus of the same type when a `child` `<li>` was clicked.

I 'fixed' this problem by using the `if` clause to determine if the item being clicked was also the item that was currently open, but I want to take it a step further and make it so that if the *parent* `ul` is clicked **again**, it will close the menu. I am having a great deal of misunderstanding as to how to approach this. I attempted to stop the propagation of the children elements, but it yields the same results. Can anyone assist?

## wiring (document load)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $('[data-role="sidebar-dropdown"]').drawer({
                    open: 'sidebar-dropdown-open',
                    css: '.sidebar-dropdown-open'
                });
        });
```

## html

```
<ul>
    <li class=" dropdown" data-role="sidebar-dropdown">
        <a href="pages/.." class="remote">Link Text</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu light sidebar-dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="remote" href="pages/...">Link Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="remote" href="pages/...">Link Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="remote" href="pages/...">Link Text</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

## JavaScript

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.drawer = function (options) {
        // Create some defaults, extending them with any options that were provided
        var settings = $.extend({
            open: 'open',
            css: '.open'
        }, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                // slide up all open dropdown menus
                $(settings.css).not($(this)).each(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass(settings.open);
                    // retrieve the appropriate menu item
                    var $menu = $(this).children(".dropdown-menu, .sidebar-dropdown-menu");
                    // slide down the one clicked on.
                    $menu.slideUp('fast');
                    $menu.removeClass('active');
                });


                // mark this menu as open
                $(this).addClass(settings.open);

                // retrieve the appropriate menu item
                var $menu = $(this).children(".dropdown-menu, .sidebar-dropdown-menu");
                // slide down the one clicked on.
                $menu.slideDown(100);
                $menu.addClass('active');
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                
            }).on("mouseleave", function () {
                $(this).children(".dropdown-menu").hide().delay(300);
            });

        })
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery events you can read the node which initiated the event by referencing `e.target`.

```
if ($(e.target).is("li")) { // do something only if the clicked element was a li }
```

Regarding closing elements which are not children, instead of doing a global selector `$(selector)` you should instead do a selector relative to your initiating dom node. It's a common practice to pass `this` and stashing it inside your jQuery plugin.

`return this.each(function(this)) { var $node = $(this); }`

Then all lookups would be done like

`$node.find(selector).doStuff()`

Comment: @roasted fixed. You are correct it is wise to store jQuery node collections with the `$`.

Comment: Is that not what I am doing with the line `return this.each(function () {` ? I thought that is what I was doing already.

Comment: Sort of... except inside of the `each()` you need a way to reference the `plugin parent` no matter what callback you are inside of. In example, inside the click handler, `this` becomes the clicked node, and not the top level `plugin node` which was built as your `drawer()`.

Comment: Give me a moment, I am very lost as to what you are saying, but I will try to make some changes and see if I comprehend it.

Comment: So it should look more like ...   `return this.each(function () {
   var $node = $(this);

   $node.on('click', function (e) {`

Comment: Yes, you are on your way. Then inside the `$node.on()` you'd do `$node.find(settings.css)` and it'll only affect the items inside that drawer and won't affect other drawers on the page. In general you rarely want jQuery plugins to *leak* out beyond the node collection that initiated it, unless by design. This pattern ensures you can have multiple drawers without conflicts.

Comment: Alright, I am completely lost. Should I mark this one as resolved and start a new question for this specific clarification?

Comment: Wait, so I want functions above the `each` that can be called within the `$node.find`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having difficulty even figuring out what to ask in a new question now. This is really getting confusing.

Comment: Wait, I think there is a disconnect here. I have it that way because I __want__ it to examine other drawers on the page. It is only supposed to keep one drawer open at a time.